# Why does a free function work but its equivalent in lambda fails to compile?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++23

The following `get` function will return an array of strings using the variadic arguments. It also handles the case with providing integers by simply converting them.
I provided two versions of this conversion function, one being a lambda and the other as a free function.

Can some please provide an explanation to why using a lambda fails to compile while a seemingly identical free function works fine. What changes would be required to make the lambda case work?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <ranges>
#include <format>
#include <array>
#include <type_traits>

// free function converter
template <typename KEY>
auto convert_to_string_view(const KEY& key)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_integral_v<KEY> && !std::is_same_v<KEY, bool>)
        return std::to_string(key);
    else
        return key;
}

// make an array out of varargs
template <typename T, typename... Args>
inline std::array<std::common_type_t<Args...>, sizeof...(Args)>
 make_array_from_vars(const Args&... args)
    requires (std::is_constructible_v<std::common_type_t<Args...>, Args> && ...)
{
    return { args... };
}



template<typename... KEYS>
auto get(KEYS... keys) {

    // lambda 
    auto convert_to_sv = [](const auto& key){
            if constexpr (std::is_integral_v<decltype(key)> && !std::is_same_v<decltype(key), bool>) {
                return std::to_string(key); 
            }
            else {
                return key;
            }
        };
    return make_array_from_vars<std::string_view>(convert_to_string_view(keys)...);
// using the lambda
    //return make_array_from_vars<std::string_view>(convert_to_sv(keys)...); FAILS

}

int main() {
    auto d = std::string("blablabla");
    auto tuple_range = get(d.append("!asdsads"), "blas", 0, 0);
    std::cout << tuple_range[0] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The specific issue here is that your function template and your lambda are checking different things:

```cpp
template <typename KEY>
auto convert_to_string_view(const KEY& key)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_integral_v<KEY> && !std::is_same_v<KEY, bool>)
```

vs

```cpp
auto convert_to_sv = [](const auto& key){
    if constexpr (std::is_integral_v<decltype(key)> && !std::is_same_v<decltype(key), bool>) {
```

The function template is checking whether the type parameter `KEY` is integral and not `bool`. The lambda is doing the same check for `decltype(key)`.

Now, considering calling both with an `int`. The function template deduces `KEY=int` and checks `int`. The lambda implicitly deduces `int` as well, but `decltype(key)` isn't `int` - it's `int const&`, because that's the type of the variable. Indeed, `integral_v<decltype(key)>` is *never* true - because references aren't integral.

To make them line up, you can introduce a template parameter and then do the same check:

```cpp
auto convert_to_sv = []<class K>(K const& key){
    if constexpr (std::is_integral_v<K> && !std::is_same_v<K, bool>) {
```

This would now have identical meaning.

---

In general the abbreviated function template syntax is only useful if you really actually don't need the type of the variable. Once you start needing it - getting it using `decltype` is now longer than writing a normal function template declaration to begin with.